# Define Guzzle Content-Length

Tags: guzzle6, guzzle

I am trying to send a request with a content length set by myself and not by guzzle. ( guzzle 6)

```
$res = $client->request('POST', $url, ['headers' => ['Content-Length' => 32]];
```

However this stops the request from sending !

I am doing this because my URL has a query string and i need the content length to be set. Not doing so sets a Content-Length: 0 by guzzle - how can i define all headers and stop guzzle from doing this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly with Guzzle (just add a missed bracket in the end ;).

You probably get an exception, but it's because the server responds with `413 Request entity too large`, and Guzzle converts it to exception (see [`http_errors`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors) to control this behaviour). Because you don't provide the request body at all.

Anyway, I don't get it, how the query string is connected to `Content-Length` header. The header defined length of the request body, but the query string is not a part of the body, so there is no connection.